# Configuring ubuntu as router

Tags: network-manager, iptables, docker, router, dnsmasq

I have a device which sends meter data to its maker site, using the MQTT protocol.

I intend to capture this information, routing it to my ubuntu PC, where I have setup a docker container with RabbitMQ Server. Below a small diagram depicting my current home network.

[my home network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/475B1.png)

Since I am a beginner regarding ubuntu configuration and networking, I come here to ask for your help regarding what configuration should I do to achieve my goal, knowing that:

- I can only configure the device IP;
- I was planning in using my ubuntu PC as the router for the device and using it to block internet access to the device;
- My ubuntu PC only have one network card;
- I only have one router, and I would like a solution where I do not need
  additional hardware

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/ for how to set it up. This seems like a general docker or networking question; it does not seem Ubuntu-specific.

Comment: I do not think you can do what you want without a 2nd NIC (Network Interface Card) in your Ubuntu PC that implements 192.168.5.1/24 (actually 192.168.5.X, where X is whatever you want, within range limits).

Comment: @DougSmythies and what about a virtual ip attached to the NIC? How can I configure it?

Comment: have you considered just capturing traffic with wireshark and then setting up a redirect with your PC acting as the "maker" and then resending with the PC posing as the device. Easier if you runa DNS service and can control the traffic. You can provide a dhcp lease to the device that gives your PC as DNS and default route. You could remap using bind to your local service and send nothing to the maker if you are trying to get the stuff to run locally only

Comment: @Crighton makes good point. If the Device were at 192.168.2.223, and if it thinks that the gateway is the Ubuntu server at 192.168.2.224, then it would send packets via the server which could watch for them via iptables, and redirect them to the docker instance at 172.90.0.15 via the bridge at 172.90.0.1. It would take me much much more time than available to provide example needed iptables rules.